# jQuery effect repeating

Tags: jquery

I created a menu on my site which has a repeating problem.

Here is example of the problem http://www.screenr.com/qc78 and here is my `.js` file https://gist.github.com/2003403

Does someone know better solution for my `.js` code?

Comment: The menu item slides down fine for me using Firefox. No repeats after leaving menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will most likely want to use jquery's [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

`function(){$(this).find('ul.sub-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp(180)}`

this is untested but should get you on the right track.